# UIImage Gif loading delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, gif

I am using [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff)'s `Gif` class to create a Gif `UIImage`. https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

Load it with this :

```
let fileUrl = NSURL(string: "some url" as! String)
let Gif = UIImage.animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL(fileUrl!)
imageview.image=Gif
```

The thing is that it takes time, a lot of time, like 7 seconds till you see the image.

I would like to preload it in some way, or at least get a delegate when finish loading.

What are my options here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Grand Central Dispatch (or GCD) to perform this task in the background.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    // This will happen in the background
    let fileUrl = NSURL(string: "some url" as! String)
    let gif = UIImage.animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL(fileUrl!)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // Always update UI on the main thread
        imageview.image = gif
    }
}
```

This will still take however long it takes to load the gif but it won't lock up the UI so the user can do things while the gif loads.